# What is the input data for Octomap algorthim?

Tags: ros2, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI every body…

i am new at ROS world i am trying to implement octomap, but first i have to learn more about it.

Does any one tell me what is the input data should i feed to the Octomap ?
how much SLAM related to Octomap?
if i have 3d ultrasonic spare point cloud, can i mapping them with Octomap?
can i use Octomap for localization?

what is the minimum hardware requirement needed for good Octomap implementation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326312/what-is-the-input-data-for-octomap-algorthim?/) by [MjdKassem](https://answers.ros.org/users/43130/mjdkassem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I might be able to answer some of the questions you have. Octomap accepts `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` message type as its input. (It might accept other point cloud types too). The [`Octomap research paper`](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Ehornunga/pub/hornung13auro.pdf) contains most of the things you need to know about its background.

I have tested Octomap in a `raspberry-pi 3B`, which has 1GB RAM, and a 4 x ARM Cortex processor. It can process an octomap in an acceptable speed, with a 4 cm resolution. But I strongly recommend a computer with higher hardware specifications if you need to build a coloured octomap, or if you need a higher resolution.

For localization, you can use `ROS navigation stack`, which can be aided by your Octomap.

---

Originally posted by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) with karma: 79 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MjdKassem](https://answers.ros.org/users/43130/mjdkassem/) on 2019-06-20**:
What do you mean by sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.?
Is there any another type of that point?
If I have real sensor like Lidar ...,does octomap deal with physical sensors directly?
You can link me some tutorial because I am just a
ROS, maybe it is early to ask like that quesion, but I have to prepare  proposal about my future work
So I have to imagine the wider idea about my research..
Thank you for your response

**Comment by [Bwmetis](https://answers.ros.org/users/54197/bwmetis/) on 2020-05-20**:
@Tharush - what camera did you use? We're using a similar setup for some of our investigation ( also the Ultrasonic > PCL map) work.

**Comment by [TharushiDeSilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/40232/tharushidesilva/) on 2020-05-29**:
I used a Microsoft Kinect 360. It's a RGB-D camera